# Java grammar questions

Tags: java, android

I am learning Android and taking the MOOC offered by Maryland University.

In one of the lectures I noticed the following line of code:

```
      String output = (val == answer) ? "42" : "We may never know";
```

My guess is that this is equivalent to:

```
      if(val == answer){
          String output = "42";
      }else{
          String output = "We may never know";
      }
```

Is my assumption correct?

PS: Is there anywhere besides coursera where I can take certified android classes online?

Comment: You would need to declare `String output;` outside the `if/else`

Comment: On a side note, avoid ternary expression because it's not convenient for debugging (think of breakpoint). It doesn't cost more to use if / else.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html - it's a *ternary* operator.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost correct, it's actually like this:

```
  String output;
  if(val == answer){
      output = "42";
  }else{
      output = "We may never know";
  }
```

BR Erik

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is *almost* correct. The ternary expression would be more accurately represented as:

```
String output;
if (val == answer) {
    output = "42";
}
else {
    output = "We may never know";
}
```

In your original version, `output` is only available within the scope of the if/else blocks, since you declare it inside them. Declaring it outside the scope means you'll be able to use the value later. However, as Hariharan pointed out, using `==` for string comparison is a no-no in Java; you're comparing the raw objects, not the string contents. You'll want to replace your `val == answer` with `val.equals(answer)` to get a proper result.

Edit: If `val` and `answer` aren't strings, disregard the portion about using `.equals()`. I (and apparently everyone else who answered this question) made the bad assumption that they were, since everything else was strings. `.equals()` should be used for strings and any other complex object, `==` can be safely used for primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct (almost). It's called [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a). Your logic is good but you must take care that the variable is initialized outside of the if-else statement.

```
String output;
if (val == answer) {
    output = "42";
} else {
    output = "We may never know";
}
```

If the variable would be defined inside if and else blocks you would not be able to use it after the `}` sign because it would fall out of the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are totally right. It's so called `ternary` operator. take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

And a small note: it's weird to declare the same variable twice inside conditional blocks. Declare it somewhere outside .